# How to get rid of non-ascii characters in Perl & Python [both]?

Tags: python, perl, pdf

How to get rid of non-ascii characters like "^L,¢,â" in Perl & Python ? Actually while parsing PDF files in Python & Perl. I'm getting these special characters. Now i have text version of these PDF files, but with these special characters. Is there any function available which will make insures that a file or a variable should not contain any non-ascii character.

Comment: What encoding does your PDF parser output?

Comment: If the characters produce symbols I think they must be ASCII charaters. Which subset of ASCII do you want to see?

Comment: @pavium: There is no such thing as a *subset of ASCII*. It's a collection of 128 characters, 33 of which are unprintable and that's it. You probably mean the ISO 8859 encodings which fill the other 128 characters with various symbols.

Comment: That was my point -- all ASCII characters are equally valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct answer to your question, in Python, is to use `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`, on the Unicode string in question. This will convert the Unicode string to an ASCII string and take out any non-ASCII characters:

```
>>> u'abc\x0c¢â'.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
'abc\x0c'
```

Note that it did not take out the '\x0c'. I put that in because you mentioned the character "^L", by which I assume you mean the form-feed character '\x0c' which can be typed with Ctrl+L. That *is* an ASCII character, and if you want to take that out, you will also need to write some other code to remove it, such as:

```
>>> str(''.join([c for c in u'abc\x0c¢â' if 32 <= ord(c) < 128]))
'abc'
```

BUT this possibly won't help you, because I suspect you don't just want to delete these characters, but actually resolve problems relating to why they are there in the first place. In this case, it could be because of Unicode encoding issues. To deal with that, you will need to ask much more specific questions with specific examples about what you expect and what you are seeing.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, some Perl solutions. Both return `,,`. Unlike the accepted Python answer, I have used no magic numbers like 32 or 128. The constants here can be looked up much easier in the documentation.

```
use 5.014; use Encode qw(encode); encode('ANSI_X3.4-1968', "\cL,¢,â", sub{q()}) =~ s/\p{PosixCntrl}//gr;

use 5.014; use Unicode::UCD qw(charinfo); join q(), grep { my $u = charinfo ord $_; 'Basic Latin' eq $u->{block} && 'Cc' ne $u->{category} } split //, "\cL,¢,â";
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can (ab)use the encode function for this purpose (Python 3 prompt):

```
>>> "hello swede åäö".encode("ascii", "ignore")
b'hello swede '
```

åäö yields encoding errors, but since I have the errors flag on "ignore", it just happily goes on. Obviously this can mask other errors.

If you want to be absolutely sure you are not missing any "important" errors, register an error handler with `codecs.register_error(name, error_handler)`. This would let you specify a replacement for each error instance.

*Also note, that in the example above using Python 3 I get a bytes object back, I would need to convert back to Unicode proper should I need a string object.*

Comment: In Python 3, you probably want to decode that back into a string again (`decode('ascii')`). As it stands, `b'hello swede '` is not a string at all, but a sequence of bytes, which won't be very useful when dealing with text.

Comment: @mguica: Well aware of that, just added info on that caveat. But thanks for the heads up :)